# Find a property of groups that is inherited by quotients but not by subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, quotient-group

This is **Exercise 4.6a** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgroup-theory%5D+inherited+by+quotients+but+not+by+subgroups+) and [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Inherited%20by%20quotients%20but%20not%20by%20subgroup&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

From p.116 of Roman's book,

> **Definition**: Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a property of groups. [ . . . ] We write $G\in \mathcal{P}$ if $G$ has property $\mathcal{P}$. [ . . . ] A property $\mathcal{P}$ of groups is *inherited* by subgroups if $$G\in \mathcal{P}\text{ and }H\le G\implies H\in \mathcal{P},$$ and $\mathcal{P}$ is inherited by quotients if $$G\in \mathcal{P}\text{ and }H\unlhd G\implies G/H\in \mathcal{P}.$$

### The Question:

> Find a property of groups that is inherited by quotients but not by subgroups.

### Thoughts:

My first guess - I don't know why - was to let $\mathcal{P}$ be "nonabelian", which fell quickly in the light that $G/G=\{G\}$ is abelian for all groups $G$.

Having $\mathcal{P}$ be "abelian" won't  work, since it is inherited by both quotients and subgroups; <s>out goes "cyclic" along with it.</s>

"Finite" is not an example, obviously.

"Solvable" is inherited by both quotients and subgroups. This can be checked on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group). (I haven't done the Maths, ironically; but with such a standard property of a group, I reckon it's more reliable here than not).

<s>All nilpotent groups are solvable, so they're out; the same goes for supersolvable groups and, in turn, metacyclic groups. Metabelian groups are also solvable.</s>

"Simple" [appears not to work](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simple+group#:%7E:text=Definition,-Standard%20definition&text=A%20simple%20group%20is%20a,G%2F%7B1%7D%20itself.).

---

It would be fiendish if Roman had not defined a group property as required prior to the exercise, so, if all else fails, I could sieve through the definitions in the first 144 pages; this is cheating though (and quite a daunting task!).

Please help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being finitely generated is such a property.

Let $F_n$ denote the free group on $n$ generators. If $F_n\to G$ witnesses that $G$ is f.g. then $F_n\to G\to G/H$ witnesses that the quotient also is, while $F_2$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $F_\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I should have known that one!

Comment: @Shaun also having Kazhdan's property (T) should work for a fancier example.

Answer (score 5):

An example of a **first-order** property which is inherited by quotients but not by subgroups is $\forall x\exists y[y^2=x]$. It is inherited by quotients because it's a positive sentence; it's not inherited by subgroups because it holds in $(\mathbb Q,+)$ but not in $(\mathbb Z,+)$.

Nobody asked about products but let me also remark that this property, being defined by a Horn sentence, is also preserved by (finite or infinite) direct products, and even reduced direct products.

Comment: This is interesting! Thank you! What name does this type of group theory go by? (Please excuse my ignorance.)

Comment: I have no idea. (Sorry, I'm not an algebraist, let alone a group theorist!) The much stronger property of being a *divisible group* would also work here.

Answer (score 4):

Being perfect is such an example. If $G$ is perfect, then $G/N$ is also perfect for all normal subgroups $N$ of $G$ since in general $(G/N)' = G'N/N$. But perfectness is clearly not preserved by subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

The property of having no nontrivial quotient groups (aka being simple or the trivial group).

Comment: The trivial group does not count as simple, so $G/G$ is not simple.

Comment: Its a definitional edge case that doesnt break the example though

Comment: I beg to differ. Edge cases are a handy bunch

Comment: Yeah, the trivial group not being simple is handy because you dont have to mention it in the classification, but otherwise its an artificial edge case.

Comment: Anyway, the point was just that the property of 0 and G being the only normal subgroups of a group G works for this question (in case it wasn't clear)

Comment: Fair enough, @Ben (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The property of being a $T$- group is an example.  That's that every subnormal subgroup (normal subgroup of a normal subgroup) is normal.

The property is inherited by normal subgroups, but not by subgroups in general.

And it's inherited by homomorphic images, hence quotients.